# MySQL Wordpress Query: Select posts by meta value but also include category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Okay, trying to pull off some ninja development here, but getting a little stuck. I require the help of a true expert here. Thanks in advance.

This Query works excellent to return post information and category from outside of Wordpress:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID,wp_posts.post_title,wp_terms.name as category FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
```

Now, this query works great for filtering by the company name, which is a meta field stored in the postmeta table. (The {$q} below is the sanitized company name)

```
SELECT ID,post_title,post_date,post_name,post_author FROM wp_posts,wp_postmeta 
WHERE ID = wp_postmeta.post_id AND meta_key = 'company'
AND meta_value = \"{$q}\" AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Anyway, both queries work great on their own. However, I want to combine them into one query so that I can select the category but still filter by company.

Any thoughts? I would love to hear your ideas on how to solve this problem. I'd give you 3x points for this answer if I could.

Comment: Output of first query: All Post ID's, titles, and category for all posts/companies in database. Output of second query: All posts by a specific company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID,wp_posts.post_title,wp_terms.name as vert FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships on wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy on wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wp_posts.ID IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'company' AND meta_value = \"{$q}\" ) LIMIT 0,99999
```